# Operating Systems: IRETQ Instruction

Tags: unix, exception, operating-system, system-calls, interrupt

I have few doubts regarding the IRETQ instruction implemented in  UNIX .

**Does IRETQ instruction called only for exception handling and not for syscall?**

**Does IRETQ returns to the process which caused the exception/interrupt or is it determined by the scheduler which procees to return to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IREQ is an Intel processor instruction. It is not implemented in Unix.

> Does IRETQ instruction called only for exception handling and not for syscall?

It is also used to return from interrupts.

> Does IRETQ returns to the process which caused the exception/interrupt or is it determined by the scheduler which procees to return to?

It returns to the process that was interrupted. The processor has no knowledge of the scheduler.